# container fit to content (multi lines)

Tags: html, css

I think it's a common issue but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have this case : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjWNMr

I want my container's width to fit its content. This works fine when the children are on the same row. But if we reduce the width of therender viewport and if the children are on two rows or more, the container's width doesn't fit anymore its content.

Here is the code :

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="dub"></div>
  <div class="dub"></div>
  <div class="dub"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container {
  background: grey;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  /*float: left;
  overflow: auto;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

#container::after {
  clear: left;
}

.dub {
  width: 440px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: left;
}
```

Thanks and sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: Do you want the 3 Divs always on the same line?

Comment: no, that isn't necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `flex-layout`. Open this snippet in full screen.

give `display: flex` and `flex-flow: row wrap` to parent element.
and `flex: 1 100%` to child to occupy the entire space.

in the media query, give `flex: 1 auto` to child for normal `inline` display

Change value in the media query for your convenience.

```css
#container {
  background: grey;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  /*float: left;
  overflow: auto;*/
  display: inline-block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#container::after {
  clear: left;
}

.dub {
  width: 440px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: left;
  flex: 1 100%;
 
}

@media all and (min-width: 1360px) {
  .dub { flex: 1 auto; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="dub"></div>
  <div class="dub"></div>
  <div class="dub"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but children need to have a fixed width/height >< and if the container is too short, children go on multi lines